# implementation of 'Multiservice' cascade action request for Java AWS microservice app

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, microservices

I'm not very mature in microservice architecture so I got stuck with the following task:

There is a request that comes to service A which should trigger a bunch of cascade delete actions for other services:

1. Service A (the one which consumes actual delete API call) should delete requested data from Elastic search (Service A communicates directly to ES)
2. Service B should delete everything from DynamoDB as consequence of this delete action (Service B communicates directly to Dynamo)
3. Service C should delete data from RDB (Service C communicates directly to RDB)
4. S3 storage data which relates to the requested data also should be deleted.
5. Redshift data also should be deleted

Of course this request must be asynchronous. And I want to come up with a sort of lightweight decision (at least without introducing Kafka for it :D).

I'm using spring boot.

Could you please provide me with some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

A great fit for this use-case is the [Gateway Aggregation Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/gateway-aggregation). The main idea is to off-load the request dispatching logic to a separate component (gateway) which takes care of retries, circuit breaking, marshalling, etc.

The gateway should be a thin layer (it can be another spring-boot app), and you can dispatch the requests in async way by using the [built-in support](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/).

If you consider that it doesn't make sense to create this new layer, you can call the other services from your app directly (using the built-in async support mentioned above).